# Using doctest on class property with py.test

Tags: python, unit-testing, properties, pytest, doctest

I try to test a property with a doctest in py.test but I get a NameError saying that the class is not defined.

Here's a little example:

```
class ExampleClass:

    def __init__(self, attribute):
        self.attribute = attribute

    @property
    def attribute_squared(self):
        """
        Examples:
            >>> ExampleClass(attribute=2).attribute_squared
            4
        """
        return self.attribute ** 2
```

When running it whin py.test I get:

```
Error
**********************************************************************
Line 3, in ExampleClass
Failed example:
    ExampleClass(attribute=2)
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pycharm\docrunner.py", line 140, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest ExampleClass[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        ExampleClass(attribute=2).attribute_squared
    NameError: name 'ExampleClass' is not defined
```

Is there a way to test class properties with or should I write a real test?

Comment: Looks like it's a configuration issue with PyCharm. If I copy your example (and fix the doctest errors), the test succeeds with `pytest --doctest-modules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found that the test doesn't pass only when I do right click/Run 'Doctest attribute_squared' in Pycharm.
When running pytest, the test passes.

Comment: Reported as a bug in PyCharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40089